# Handling chained and inner promise not properly executing

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

I believe my `promises` aren't being finished because I'm not handling them correctly. At the end of my code, within `Promise.all()`, `console.log(payload)` is displaying `{}`. When it should display something like this:

```
{
  project1: {
    description: '...',
    stats: {python: 50, css: 50}
  },
    project2: {
    description: '...',
    stats: {python: 25, css: 75}
  },
  project3: {
    description: '...',
    stats: {python: 10, css: 90}
  }
}
```

code:

```
app.get("/github", (req, res) => {
    const authorizationHeader = {headers: {Authorization: 'Basic ' + keys.github.accessToken}};
    const user = 'liondancer';
    const githubEndpoint = 'api.github.com/repos/';
    var payload = {};
    let promises = req.query.projects.map(project => {
        let datum = {};
        const githubAPIUrl = path.join(githubEndpoint, user, project);
        return fetch('https://' + githubAPIUrl + '/languages', authorizationHeader).then(res => {
            // Get Languages of a project
            if (!isStatus2XX(res)) {
                throw 'Status code not 2XX:' + res.status;
            }
            return res.json();
        }).then(res => {
            let languagePercentages = {};
            let total = 0;
            // get total
            Object.keys(res).forEach(key => {
                total += Number.parseInt(res[key]);
            });
            // compute percentages
            Object.keys(res).forEach(key => {
                languagePercentages[key] = (Number.parseInt(res[key]) / total * 100).toFixed(1);
            });
            datum.stats = languagePercentages;
            // Get description of a project
            fetch('https://' + githubAPIUrl).then(res => {
                if (!isStatus2XX(res)) {
                    throw 'Status code not 2XX: ' + res.status;
                }
                return res.json();
            }).then(res => {
                datum.description = res.description;
                payload[project] = datum;
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Github API error: ' + err);
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log(payload);
        res.send(payload);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('nothing ever works...: ' + err);
    });
});
```

At first I replaced `.map` with `.forEach()` to have the code execute and the code seemed to have worked properly. `payload` had the values I expected. However, now that I want to send the aggregated results, I cant seem the properly execute the promises in the correct order or if at all.

Comment: Since your `req.query.projects.map(...)` callback doesn't return a value, you are getting an array of `undefined` values. You need to `return` the promise you are creating (i.e. `return fetch(...)`) so that you get an array of promises.

Comment: @FelixKling I had `return` in front at first. The code without `return` is the code I was debugging with. Added `return`  and for the same value. Good looking out

Comment: Similar inside the `.then` callback: You have to do `return fetch(...)`, otherwise the promises are not properly chained.

Comment: @FelixKling could have sworn I tried that... Your suggestion worked! Thanks! Answer and I will gladly accept!

Comment: By the way, is it not better to take out the last two .then() which are after the return fetch('https://' + githubAPIUrl), to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 1):

just change this line

```
fetch('https://' + githubAPIUrl).then(res => {
```

into this

```
return fetch('https://' + githubAPIUrl).then(res => {
```

so promise.all will resolve after all nested promises have resolved so payload filled up.